# Expectation of observation of first value of a random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value

Given $X_k$, k $\geq 0$ be iid random variables with pmf

$$p_j = P(X_1 = j), 1 \leq j \leq m; \sum_{j = 1}^{m}p_j = 1$$

Let T = min{n > $0$ : $X_n$ = $X_o$} denote the first time we observe the initial value again. Compute E[T].

The only thing I can make out is that the $X_n$ seems to be of a binomial distribution, with probability taking on $\frac{1}{m}$. Beyond that, even if I do know what $X_1$ is, with no indication / pattern of how the random variables will behave, how should I go about solving the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional expectation is useful here. Here are some steps:

1) Understand that it suffices to compute $E[T|X_0 = i]$.

2) Understand that $E[T|X_0 = i]$ is the same as the first time you hit $i$ ignoring $X_0$. Show that either:

a) It is a geometric r.v with parameter $p_i$ OR

b) Use a clever recursion which you may have encountered while solving problems of this type.

I will update my answer if you need more help. But try thinking along these lines first.

**Update:** 
\begin{eqnarray}
E[T] &=& \sum_{k=1}^m E[T|X_0=k]Pr(X_0=k) \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{p_k}.p_k \\
&=& \sum_{k=1}^m 1 \\
&=& m
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: This approach is very similar as @Michael Lugo, so I tried the following. I took out P($X_o$) = j, which equals $\frac{1}{m}$, as I mentioned before in the question. This left me with the conditional expectation in your expression above, and since I wanted to find when $X_n$ = $X_0$, I can hence substitute it to become E(T|$X_n$ = j). Since n can then be any number, I let it be E(T|$X_1$ = j). This is where I am now stuck. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Reading through your hints again, I realised since $E(T|X_1 = j)$ is a geometric r.v with parameter $p_j$, I could basically just use the formula for the expectation formula $\frac{1}{p}$. Hence, my final answer is $\frac{1}{p_j}$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Isn't $P(X_0 = j)= p_j$ ? You have mentioned that $X_i $ are iid for $i \ge 0$. So how'd it become $1/m$ ? Also your understanding is correct.

Comment: That makes sense...but I was thinking since there are m different possibilities, then for the very first trial (i.e. $X_o$) then it would just work like a binomial with each possibility having probability $\frac{1}{m}$. How should I reconcile this understanding?

Comment: Possibilities $\ne$ Probabilities, unless you are given that it is uniformly distributed. E.g. if I'm given a loaded die where 6 happens with probability 1/2, then there is no way that probability of 6 is 1/6. Even though in any die there are 6 possibilities / outcomes.

Comment: I see....so in this case the final answer should be $p_j * \frac{1}{p_j} = 1$ then. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have to use the formula given in the other answer. The answer will be $m$ after summing.

Comment: Can I check how you got m? I got a double summation. After expanding out the equation, $\sum_{j = 1}^{m}P(X_o = j) = mp_j$. But my expectation is $\sum_{j = 1}^{m}E(T|X_1 = j)$. The expectation for each $X_n$ is $\frac{1}{p_j}$ since it is a geometric r.v. as you have pointed out. But since I sum it from 1 up till m, shouldn't the entire sum of the expectation be $\frac{m}{p_j}$ instead? Hence, the product of the two terms should be $m^2$ instead?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting confused. The expression $\sum_{j=1}^m P(X_0 = j) = 1$ and not what you've written. Look at the formula carefully and then apply. I have updated my answer to illustrate this. Also $\sum_{j=1}^m E[T|X_1 = j]$ isn't the right formula. You forgot to multiply each term in the sum by $p_j$.

Comment: I see where I have gone wrong now...thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

It really helps to know what $X_0$ is.  We don't, but we won't let that stop us - instead we'll look at all the possible values at once.  By the law of total expectation,

$$E(T) = \sum_{j=1}^m E(T|X_0 = j) P(X_0 = j)$$

Now the distribution of $T$ conditional on $X_0 = j$ is something simple.

Comment: I drew inspiration from your hint, and came up with this approach. I took out P($X_o$) = j, which equals $\frac{1}{m}$, as I mentioned before in the question. This left me with the conditional expectation in your expression above, and since I wanted to find when $X_n$ = $X_0$, I can hence substitute it to become E(T|$X_n$ = j). Since n can then be any number, I let it be E(T|$X_1$ = j). This is where I am now stuck. Am I on the right track?